# Why do I have a localization in the Bundle.Main.localizations that I have deleted from my xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I think this is a simple fix, somewhere.

When I `print(Bundle.main.localizations)`,

I get:

`["de", "ar", "en", "es", "it", "Base", "fr", "pt-PT"]`

However, I recently removed the Arabic strings file and removed the localization from the project:

[image]

How do I remove Arabic as being one of the localizations? I'm not sure about the consequences of the situation from a user standpoint and wouldn't want any weird iTunesConnect/AppStore stuff happening, for instance somehow advertising that there is an Arabic localization available, when there isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, solution is to make sure you clean your build folder if you remove a localization:

`Command + Shift + K`

Rerunning will display updated localizations.